# SQL Error (2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'X.X.X.X.' (10051) - What does this error mean?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database

I get following error when i try to connect via "HeidiSQL" to my database server (local network)

**SQL Error (2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'X.X.X.X.' (10051)**

SSH Connection via Putty works fine. I checked the my.cnf file on the server (Ubuntu), but settings like bind_address are correct.

Is it possible that my wireless modem (SpeedTouch) makes this trouble? (Because my provider changed the download speed) !

Comment: you check heidi forums? http://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=5428

Answer (score 1):

If you can't connect to your server directly, but can connect through a SSH tunnel then usually the server is just only listening on `localhost`. As far as I know, that is the default on Ubuntu system.

When you say the bind-address is "correct", then I assume you changed it to your public IP address. In that case, make sure you restarted `mysqld` after you made that change.
Additionally, the listening port (3306 by default) could be blocked in `ufw` or some other firewall in place.

Comment: +1 for firewall. Also quite likely that `skip-networking` is enabled in the config.

Comment: Ubuntu's default is to just listen on `localhost`, not to have `skip-networking`

Comment: Make sure the SQL server is listening on 0.0.0.0 not localhost, that's a good start